# using ANT , How to create a patternset inside scriptdef?

Tags: java, ant, build

I am trying to create a patternset in a scripdef, for example :

```
    <scriptdef name="extract-files" language="javascript">
       unjar = self.project.createTask("unjar");    
       unjar.setDest(new File(project.getProperty("tmp.folder")));
       patternset = new PatternSet();
       patternset.setRefid("patternid");
       unjar.addPatternset(patternset);
       unjar.execute();
     </scriptdef>
```

I didn't put the complete code , but that script fails in patternset = new PatternSet();
What is the way to create a pattern set in this kind of script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following as given [here](http://jayflowers.com/WordPress/?p=213)

```
importClass(Packages.org.apache.tools.ant.types.PatternSet);
var patternSet = new PatternSet();
```